# Convert ISO datetime to datetime and char for calculation

Tags: date, datetime, sas, iso

I have a dataset with a variable with a date ISO and I need to compare it with another date to calculation duration.

```
| ID       | startdt | enddt
| -------- | -------- |
| US12     | 2012-05-01T14:34-05:00|2012-05-01T14:45-05:00
| US13     | 2022-04-22T15:00-05:00|2022-04-22T17:00-05:00
```

`your text` all dates format (text)= char 256

I need to convert to a sas datetime as 2012-05-01:14:34 to assign to a new variable then I need to calculate the duration between the start and end date (which are also `ISO dates format).

```
data test (keep=stardat endat durtm);
set extest;
format stdat $20. tmdat $10. newdate datetime13.;

stardat= exst_dt;
enddat=exen_dt;
durtm=; enddat - startdat

run;
```

`The final output should contain the assignment of exst_dt and exenst into the new variable as 2012-05-01:14:34 format and the duration like a number difference between the end date and start date.

the assignment to i8601dz. format gives and error :
numeric values has been converted to character values at the places given by...

invalid argument to function input at....
mathematical operations could not performed at the following places...
Thanks,

Comment: Why does the code you show not use the variable ISOdt that you mention in the first paragraph?  Why does the code create STDAT and TMDAT as character variables and then attempt to use them in arithmetic?

Answer (score 0):

Input your datetime string with the `ANYDTDT.` informat and use `INTCK()` to compute the interval between the datetime values.

Example:

```
data have;
length id $8 isodatestring $22;
input id isodatestring;
datalines;
US12      2012-05-01T14:34-05:00
US13      2022-04-22T15:00-05:00
;

data step1;
  set have;
  isodatetime = input(isodatestring, ANYDTDTM22.);
  format isodatetime E8601DZ.;
  /* Writes datetime values for the zero meridian Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)
   * by using the ISO 8601 datetime and time zone extended notation
   * yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss+00:00.
   */ 
run;

data want;
  set step1;
  priordt = lag(isodatetime);
  dt = isodatetime;
  intervaldays = intck('dtdays', priordt, dt);

  format priordt dt e8601dz. intervaldays 12.;

  put /priordt=/+5dt=/intervaldays=;
run;
```

will Log

```
priordt=.
     dt=2012-05-01T19:34:00+00:00
intervaldays=.

priordt=2012-05-01T19:34:00+00:00
     dt=2022-04-22T20:00:00+00:00
intervaldays=3643
```

There are a number of other SAS formats you can use to display your datetimes that conform to ISO specifications.

[image]

[image]

Comment: No. This code doesn't work.

Comment: What does the log show?